# Не отображается видимый фокус на элементах

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, focus

Есть графический интерфейс, на котором выстроены флажки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которые собраны соответственно в списке `self.cbks`. 
Мне нужно переключаться между флажками с помощью клавиш, но если использовать `Tab`, то в переключении участвуют также и кнопки расположенные слева. 
Чтобы кнопки не задевались я решил выделить под переключение горячие клавиши:

Бинд клавиши:

```
QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Down), self.window, lambda dirctn='down': select(dirctn))
```

Код отвечающий за обработку:

```
def select(direction):

    if direction== 'up':
        pass
    elif direction == 'down':
        if checked_cbx == len(self.cbks)-1: # Если доходит до конца списка, возвращает в начало
            checked_cbx = 0
        else:
            checked_cbx += 1
    self.cbks[checked_cbx].setFocus() # Отображение фокуса на элементе
```

Проблема заключается в том, что фокус переключается корректно, но не отображается графически. То есть не видно выделения как например выделено слово "hunch" на изображении выше. 
Для того чтобы можно было отслеживать переключение между выделенными элементами нужно кликнуть на флажок мышкой, только в таком случае факт фокуса и его перемещение становится видимым.

Находил подобные вопросы, там была подсказка что наводить фокус на элемент нужно после инициализации окна `self.window.show()`, но это не помогло.

---

**UPD**

Добавляю пример, если использовать стрелки (вверх/вниз) и нажимать пробел то будут выделяться правильные флажки, но как я упоминал раньше не будет видно графическое выделение этих элементов. Чтобы сделать фокус видимым нужно хотя бы один раз нажать мышью.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QGridLayout

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
class WordLearn(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cb_selected = 0
        self.buttons: list[QPushButton] = self.cr_btns()
        self.checkboxes: list[QCheckBox] = self.cr_cbx()
        glo = self.build_intrfc(self.buttons, self.checkboxes)

        self.setLayout(glo)

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Down), self, lambda dr='down': self.move_focus(dr))
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Up), self, lambda dr='up': self.move_focus(dr))
        self.show()
        self.checkboxes[0].setFocus()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def cr_btns(self) -> list[QPushButton]:
        mss = list()
        names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
        for i in names:
            mss.append(QPushButton(i))
        return mss

    def cr_cbx(self) -> list[QCheckBox]:
        mss = list()
        names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
        for i in names:
            mss.append(QCheckBox(i))
        return mss

    def build_intrfc(self, buttons: list[QPushButton], cbxs: list[QCheckBox]) -> QGridLayout:
        glo = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(len(buttons)):
            glo.addWidget(buttons[i], i, 0)
            glo.addWidget( cbxs[i], i, 1)
        return glo

    def move_focus(self, dicetcion):
        if dicetcion == 'up':
            if self.cb_selected == 0:
                self.cb_selected = len(self.checkboxes) - 1
            else:
                self.cb_selected -= 1
        elif dicetcion == 'down':
            if self.cb_selected == len(self.checkboxes) - 1:
                self.cb_selected = 0
            else:
                self.cb_selected += 1
        self.checkboxes[self.cb_selected].setFocus()

WordLearn()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите для кнопок политику получения фокуса клавиатуры - `Qt.NoFocus`.

```
buttons[i].setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
```

`Qt.Key_Up`, `Qt.Key_Down`, `Qt.Key_Left`, `Qt.Key_Right` и `Qt.Key_Tab`
используются для изменения фокуса.
Попробуйте также временами нажимать `Qt.Key_Space`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QGridLayout


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class WordLearn(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cb_selected = 0
        self.buttons: list[QPushButton] = self.cr_btns()
        self.checkboxes: list[QCheckBox] = self.cr_cbx()
        glo = self.build_intrfc(self.buttons, self.checkboxes)

        self.setLayout(glo)

        ''' # уже не нужны
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Down), self, lambda dr='down': self.move_focus(dr))
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Up), self, lambda dr='up': self.move_focus(dr))
        '''
        
        self.show()
        self.checkboxes[0].setFocus()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

#    def cr_btns(self) -> list[QPushButton]:
    def cr_btns(self): # -> list[QPushButton]:
        mss = list()
        names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
        for i in names:
            mss.append(QPushButton(i))
        return mss

#    def cr_cbx(self) -> list[QCheckBox]:
    def cr_cbx(self): # -> list[QCheckBox]:
        mss = list()
        names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
        for i in names:
            mss.append(QCheckBox(i))
        return mss

#    def build_intrfc(self, buttons: list[QPushButton], cbxs: list[QCheckBox]) -> QGridLayout:
    def build_intrfc(self, buttons, cbxs):
        glo = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(len(buttons)):
            buttons[i].setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)                            # +++
            glo.addWidget(buttons[i], i, 0)
            glo.addWidget( cbxs[i], i, 1)
        return glo

    '''
    def move_focus(self, dicetcion):
        print(f'def move_focus(self, dicetcion): {dicetcion}')
        if dicetcion == 'up':
            if self.cb_selected == 0:
                self.cb_selected = len(self.checkboxes) - 1
            else:
                self.cb_selected -= 1
        elif dicetcion == 'down':
            if self.cb_selected == len(self.checkboxes) - 1:
                self.cb_selected = 0
            else:
                self.cb_selected += 1
        self.checkboxes[self.cb_selected].setFocus()
    '''
    
WordLearn()
```

P.S. У меня видимо Python не той версии установлен,
поправьте некоторые строки, которые я закомментировал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Восхитительно, подскажите, а как вернуть способность получать фокус кнопкам?

Comment: @arachnoden  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum